# Align tikz arrow heads with cells of a table - tikzmark overrides

Tags: tables, tikzmark

[image: Visual example]

I'm wondering how to move the arrow heads so that they don't intersect the text. Would be ideal to be able to align the lower arrow head with the top of the second line of numbers instead that with the base. Any idea on how to do this?

I'm using the following code to generate this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\begin{document}

\caption{}
\begin{tabular}{|lrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrl}
\hline
\multicolumn{21}{|l|}{something}\\
\hline
-1 &
11 &
21 &
31 &
41 &
51 &
61 &
71 &
81 &
91 &
101 &
\tikzmark{a}111 &
121 &
131 &
141 &
151 &
161 &
171 &
181 &
191 &
\ldots\\
&\\
\multicolumn{21}{|l}{something\tikzmark{c}}\\
&\\
-1 &
11 &
21 &
31 &
41 &
51 &
61 &
71 &
81 &
91 &
101 &
\tikzmark{b}111 &
121 &
131 &
141 &
151 &
161 &
171 &
181 &
191 &
\ldots\\
\hline
\multicolumn{21}{|r|}{something}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,
                remember picture,
                shorten >=2pt]
%
\draw [thick,->]({pic cs:c}) -- ({pic cs:a});
\draw [thick,->] ({pic cs:c}) -- ({pic cs:b});
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

---

**Update:**
I'm facing another issue. I'm writing several tables like this in my document and each table have different sets of numbers and arrows. Those arrows have to point to different numbers in different tables, eg. in table 1 the arrows point to (111,111) and in table 2 they point to (141,151).

So in table 2 I changed `tikzmark{a}` and `tikzmark{b}`, assigned to `111, 111` in table 1, to the cells containing `141` and `151` in table2.

The problem shows here. When I recompile the document both sets of arrows in table 1 and table 2 point to `141` and `151`.

It seems the `remember picture` option contained in table 2 overrides the marks contained in table 1.

I would use `tikzmark{d}`, `tikzmark{e}`, `tikzmark{f}` for table 2 and so on alphabetically for table 3, 4, etc. but I will soon run out of letters since, as I previously said, I have several tables in the chapter. Also it would become confusing to handle.

Is there a way to ''flush'' the `tikzmark` after each table so that I can use `tikzmark{a}`, `tikzmark{b}`, `tikzmark{c}` in each table without worrying of overrides?

Ps: For completeness I may say my `tabular` environments shown above are being called in the main document through-

```
\begin{table}[!h]
  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
  \centering
    \input{./path-to-tabular}
  \label{3:tab:gnomon 1-1}
\end{table}
```

with this in the preamble

```
\newcommand*\ExpandableInput[1]{\@@input#1 }% to input tables
```

Comment: You can use longer expressions for the tilzmarks, like `aa`, `ab`, `ac` for the first table and then `ba`, `bb`, `bc` ...

Answer (score 2):

Using `xshift` and `yshift` for example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|lrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrl}
\hline
\multicolumn{21}{|l|}{something}\\
\hline
-1 &
11 &
21 &
31 &
41 &
51 &
61 &
71 &
81 &
91 &
101 &
\tikzmark{a}111 &
121 &
131 &
141 &
151 &
161 &
171 &
181 &
191 &
\ldots\\
&\\
\multicolumn{21}{|l}{something\tikzmark{c}}\\
&\\
-1 &
11 &
21 &
31 &
41 &
51 &
61 &
71 &
81 &
91 &
101 &
\tikzmark{b}111 &
121 &
131 &
141 &
151 &
161 &
171 &
181 &
191 &
\ldots\\
\hline
\multicolumn{21}{|r|}{something}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,
                remember picture,
                shorten >=2pt]
%
\draw [thick,->] ([yshift=.66ex,xshift=.25ex]{pic cs:c}) -- ([yshift=-.25ex]{pic cs:a});
\draw [thick,->] ([yshift=.66ex,xshift=.25ex]{pic cs:c}) -- ([yshift=1.75ex]{pic cs:b});
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```