# Create a vertical table with labeled arrows along the sides

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, tikz-arrows, arrows

I am trying to create something that looks like the table in the image. Any ideas on how to start this?
[image]

Comment: Use `tikzmark`. There're many example here that you can find with a simple search. [Here's one of them](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/413072/204164)

Comment: You can also use the `nicematrix` package.

Answer (score 0):

I generated the following Tikz code using mathca.io

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{mathdots}
\usepackage{yhmath}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{extarrows}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows.blur}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering


\tikzset{every picture/.style={line width=0.75pt}} %set default line width to 0.75pt        

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.75pt,y=0.75pt,yscale=-1,xscale=1]
%uncomment if require: \path (0,300); %set diagram left start at 0, and has height of 300

%Shape: Rectangle [id:dp07021219230336118] 
\draw   (206,97.02) -- (304.1,97.02) -- (304.1,124.05) -- (206,124.05) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Rectangle [id:dp8733124407757347] 
\draw   (206,70) -- (304.1,70) -- (304.1,97.02) -- (206,97.02) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Rectangle [id:dp17466754847742205] 
\draw   (304.1,70) -- (402.2,70) -- (402.2,97.02) -- (304.1,97.02) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Rectangle [id:dp537494061680013] 
\draw   (304.1,97.02) -- (402.2,97.02) -- (402.2,124.05) -- (304.1,124.05) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Rectangle [id:dp41400929619239224] 
\draw   (206,124.05) -- (304.1,124.05) -- (304.1,151.07) -- (206,151.07) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Rectangle [id:dp970796300399257] 
\draw   (206,151.07) -- (304.1,151.07) -- (304.1,178.09) -- (206,178.09) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Rectangle [id:dp6331999425074073] 
\draw   (304.1,124.05) -- (402.2,124.05) -- (402.2,151.07) -- (304.1,151.07) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Rectangle [id:dp12004057707230431] 
\draw   (304.1,151.07) -- (402.2,151.07) -- (402.2,178.09) -- (304.1,178.09) -- cycle ;
%Curve Lines [id:da9209943693404814] 
\draw [color={rgb, 255:red, 20; green, 211; blue, 39 }  ,draw opacity=1 ]   (192.1,104.02) .. controls (162.55,100.08) and (145.62,136.89) .. (197.68,133.22) ;
\draw [shift={(200.1,133.02)}, rotate = 174.81] [fill={rgb, 255:red, 20; green, 211; blue, 39 }  ,fill opacity=1 ][line width=0.08]  [draw opacity=0] (8.93,-4.29) -- (0,0) -- (8.93,4.29) -- cycle    ;
%Curve Lines [id:da12343393037834005] 
\draw [color={rgb, 255:red, 20; green, 211; blue, 39 }  ,draw opacity=1 ]   (194.1,141.02) .. controls (164.55,137.08) and (147.62,173.89) .. (199.68,170.22) ;
\draw [shift={(202.1,170.02)}, rotate = 174.81] [fill={rgb, 255:red, 20; green, 211; blue, 39 }  ,fill opacity=1 ][line width=0.08]  [draw opacity=0] (8.93,-4.29) -- (0,0) -- (8.93,4.29) -- cycle    ;
%Curve Lines [id:da7349606479430006] 
\draw [color={rgb, 255:red, 20; green, 211; blue, 39 }  ,draw opacity=1 ]   (416.38,105.02) .. controls (446.73,101.08) and (464.13,137.89) .. (410.65,134.22) ;
\draw [shift={(408.16,134.02)}, rotate = 5.06] [fill={rgb, 255:red, 20; green, 211; blue, 39 }  ,fill opacity=1 ][line width=0.08]  [draw opacity=0] (8.93,-4.29) -- (0,0) -- (8.93,4.29) -- cycle    ;
%Curve Lines [id:da6595786045485434] 
\draw [color={rgb, 255:red, 20; green, 211; blue, 39 }  ,draw opacity=1 ]   (414.32,142.02) .. controls (444.68,138.08) and (462.08,174.89) .. (408.6,171.22) ;
\draw [shift={(406.1,171.02)}, rotate = 5.06] [fill={rgb, 255:red, 20; green, 211; blue, 39 }  ,fill opacity=1 ][line width=0.08]  [draw opacity=0] (8.93,-4.29) -- (0,0) -- (8.93,4.29) -- cycle    ;

% Text Node
\draw (239,102.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$100$};
% Text Node
\draw (216,75) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]   [align=left] {\textbf{length (in)}};
% Text Node
\draw (312,75) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]   [align=left] {\textbf{length (cm)}};
% Text Node
\draw (340,102.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$254$};
% Text Node
\draw (248,129.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$1$};
% Text Node
\draw (244,158.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$20$};
% Text Node
\draw (338,129.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$2.54$};
% Text Node
\draw (337,156.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$50.8$};
% Text Node
\draw (113,95.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [color={rgb, 255:red, 20; green, 211; blue, 39 }  ,opacity=1 ]  {$\cdot \frac{1}{100}$};
% Text Node
\draw (125,149.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$\textcolor[rgb]{0.08,0.83,0.15}{\cdot 20}$};
% Text Node
\draw (451,95.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [color={rgb, 255:red, 20; green, 211; blue, 39 }  ,opacity=1 ]  {$\cdot \frac{1}{100}$};
% Text Node
\draw (463,149.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$\textcolor[rgb]{0.08,0.83,0.15}{\cdot 20}$};


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```